# Issues with OpenGL and LWJGL: Syntax Error on Token "glMatrixMode"

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, pong

I want to make a 'Pong' game using lwjgl. For now, I made 2 classes: GameLoop and Inizializza. I have those 4 lines of code marked below that are giving me compile errors.  I copied that part from LJWGL wiki.

GameLoop-

```
package game.engine;

public class GameLoop 
{
    //Main
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        Inizializza finestraGioco = new Inizializza();
        finestraGioco.start();
    }
}
```

Inizializza-

```
package game.engine;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class Inizializza 
{ 
    ##This is where the code gives me errors##

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);      >>Syntax error on token "glMatrixMode", identifier expected after this token 

    GL11.glLoadIdentity();                      >>Syntax error on token "glLoadIdentity", Identifier expected after this toketn

    GL11.glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 1, -1);   >>Syntax error on token "(",= expected
                                                >>Syntax error(s) on tokens, misplaced construct(s)                       

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);       >>Syntax error on token "glMatrixMode", identifier expected after this token 
                                                >>Syntax error on tokent ".", ... expected

    public void start() 
    {
        try 
        {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800,600));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            Entità.pulisci();
            Entità.colora();
            Entità.disegna();
            Display.update();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you've just dropped those lines in the class body; they should be in a method (somewhere in your `start` method?)

Comment: Uhm ... yeah, I knew it was something stupid. Post it like a response so I will give you "answered" mark ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you've just dropped those lines in the class body; they should be in a method (somewhere in your start method?).

:)